# Why is plutil escaping forward slashes in JSON?

Tags: json, macos

I'm using the macOS [`plutil`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/plutil/) command to convert a plist file to JSON. Consider this example plist, containing an URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>https://example.com</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

When I run `plutil -convert json example.plist -o -` I see this output:

```
["https:\/\/example.com"]
```

That's not what I expected. Forward slashes don't need to be escaped in JSON output. I expected this:

```
["https://example.com"]
```

Why is `plutil` doing this?

To get rid of these unnecessary forward slashes, I'm using a little `node` script to parse the JSON and write it back out as a file. (`node` doesn't add unnecessary slahes.) Is there a way to make plutil provide my expected output without postprocessing it?

Comment: Because the [JSON standard](http://json.org) says so.

Comment: The JSON standard says that valid characters can fall in the range `'0020' . '10ffff' - '"' - '\'`. Forward slash is in that legal range. The `escape` section says that `\/` is valid, and it is, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: Since it is not mandatory, it should work both ways.